# How to do REAL Syncing Data With Firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I am learning how to “Syncing Data With Firebase Using Ionic Framework”, Here is the code of TodoController.

```
myApp.controller("TodoController", function($scope, $firebaseObject, $ionicPopup) {

$scope.list = function() {
fbAuth = fb.getAuth();
if(fbAuth) {
    var syncObject = $firebaseObject(fb.child("users/" + fbAuth.uid));
    syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");
}
}

$scope.create = function() {
$ionicPopup.prompt({
    title: 'Enter a new TODO item',
    inputType: 'text'
})
.then(function(result) {
    if(result !== "") {
        if($scope.data.hasOwnProperty("todos") !== true) {
            $scope.data.todos = [];
        }
        $scope.data.todos.push({title: result});
    } else {
        console.log("Action not completed");
    }
});
}
});
```

The problem is: list() get data from remote Firebase directly, it will not get data from local storage at first and update/sync the local data to remote Firebase(4-way Data-binding??), has Firebase any method to sync local(if wifi disconnected) and server(when wifi connected) data automatically???

Any help would be much appreciated. Best Regards.

Comment: I would not try to bind to localStorage. localStorage is a severely inadequate form of offline storage. Firebase already handles intermittent connections and caching out of the box.

Comment: David East , I got it,  thanks for your help.